# Why does the power series form of the exponential equal 0 when evaluated at 0?

Tags: analysis, power-series, exponential-function

Since $e$ is a real number I know that $e^0 = 1$, but when I enter $z=0$ into the power series definition of $e^z$ I get an output of $0$. Am I doing something wrong?

$$e^z = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}z^n$$

Setting $z=0$:

$$e^0 = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}0^n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty 0 = 0$$

What have I done wrong?

Comment: You need to know the conventions of power series, that is that $0!=1$ and $z^0=1$ (for all $z$) and then the zero-th term is indeed $1$.

Comment: Note that $0^0=1$ by definition. So the first summand is $1$.

Comment: Thank you so much! I understand now.

Comment: @Mark $0^0 = \lim_{x\to 0^+}x^x= \lim_{x\to 0^+}e^{x\ln(x)}=e^0=1$.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah That indeed gives more motivation to defining $0^0=1$, to make $x^x$ continuous at $0$. But I usually prefer to tell my students that just like with $0!=1$, this is just a good definition, which works nicely in many formulas, such as the Taylor expansion. (as otherwise we would have to write the first summand separately)

Comment: See all the other posts here about $0^0$.  For example, $0^0 = 1$ if the exponent is the integer zero (as here).  But $0^0=1$ is not so clear when the exponent is the real number zero.